# Set Current Category to Active in laravel

Tags: laravel

i am trying to Set Current Category to active when i reload my page but unfortunately it's not working please help me thanks.

**html view**

```
 <ul class='visible-links nav nav-tabs' role="tablist">
              @foreach($productCategories   as   $productCategory)
              <li>
                <a class="tab-a active-a productcategory  {{ Request::is('') ? 'active' : '' }}"  data-id="{{$productCategory->id}}"   data-toggle="tab"  href="{{$productCategory->id}}" role="tab"  data-toggle="tab">{{$productCategory->name}}
                </a>
              </li>
              @endforeach
            </ul>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('products/get-product', 'ProductController@getproduct')->name('products.getproduct');
Route::get('/products/{slug}', 'ProductController@index')->name('products');
```

Comment: can you update with: how you set the route? and how you load it in controller? in case you are using route binding

Comment: Can you show more code please

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

assuming this is from route `Route::get('/products/{slug}'...`

```
<ul class='visible-links nav nav-tabs' role="tablist">
  @foreach($productCategories as $productCategory)
  <li>
    <a class="tab-a active-a productcategory 
    {{ request()->route('slug') == $productCategory->slug ? 'active' : '' }}" 
    data-id="{{$productCategory->id}}" data-toggle="tab" href="{{$productCategory->id}}" 
    role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{$productCategory->name}}
    </a>
  </li>
  @endforeach
</ul>

//Request::route() or the helper request()->route()
```

if you are using model binding in the controller you can use `request()->route('slug')->id == $productCategory->id`

make sure that `active` class is triggering active tab, or else the `active-a` is the class triggering active tab

Comment: i have put this code it's successfully   {{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}"

Comment: @ZubairMukhtar need to match the `slug`, not the `$loop->iteration`